# Error Python 2.7 on Google App Engine - Threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have tried to move to Python 2.7 from Python 2.5 but I keep getting the same error everytime.

I have made a very simple test in Python 2.5 working with the app.yaml file and just one script main.py and it works fine. The script it just a Hello World type to check everythin works fine.

app.yaml

```
application: sparepartsfinder
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1


handlers:

- url: /blog
  script: main.py

- url: /blog/new_entry
  script: main.py
```

main.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/blog', MainPage),
                                      ('/blog/new_entry',MainPage),
                                      ('/blog/archive/.*',MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I change to Python 2.7 I follow the documents on the [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configuring_the_Application) to the letter making the changes in both the app.yaml and main.py script.

app.yaml

```
application: sparepartsfinder
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true


handlers:

- url: /blog
  script: main.py

- url: /blog/new_entry
  script: main.py 

- url: /blog/archive/.*
  script: main.py


- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello prueba!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/blog', MainPage),
                               ('/blog/new_entry',MainPage),
                               ('/blog/archive/.*',MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work either in local or when I try to upload the new configuration to the Google App Engine. ( I get always the same mistake).

I may understand the problem in my machine ( I have both Python 2.5 and 2.7 ) on a Windows XP, but not when I upload.

This is the error:

> 2012-05-04 13:02:07 Running command: "[u'C:\Python25\python2.5.exe', '-u', 'C:\Archivos >de programa\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=salvador.sanjuan@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\Documents and Settings\SSanjuan\Mis documentos\Dropbox\Dropbox\Python\SpareParts']"
>   Error parsing yaml file:
>   Invalid object:
>   threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: main.py
>     in "C:\Documents and Settings\SSanjuan\Mis documentos\Dropbox\Dropbox\Python\SpareParts\app.yaml", line 27, column 1
>   2012-05-04 13:02:31 (Process exited with code 1)

Answer (score 30):

Use `main.application` instead of `main.py` in your app.yaml. You need the former in order to set `threadsafe` to `true`.

Comment: But where is the file main.application? If I change it appears new error.                   <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: Could not find module main.app 
      args = ('Could not find module main.app',) 
      message = 'Could not find module main.app'

Comment: In the former form, `main.application` (or `main.app`) is supposed to point to an WSGIApplication object directly with dot-notation. Where is your main.py taking place BTW? If it's in under the project top directory, you can use either of `main.app` or `main.application` according to the name of your WSGIApplication object in the global scope of that file.

Comment: See also: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configuring_WSGI_Script_Handlers

Answer (score 18):

I've been having the same problem, and here's the answer.

For the Python 2.5 runtime, you are specifying a path to a file -- ie script: myfolder/myfile.py.

For the Python 2.7 runtime, you are specifying an Object.  So assumping myfile.py contains an appropriate WSGI object 'app', it's specified as script: myfolder.myfile.app.

Comment: exactly - replace `/` with `.` in your path and all is well!

Comment: Having replaced the `/` by `.` I got an `ImportError: No module named myfolder`. Solution: `touch myfolder.__init__.py`

Comment: Wow! It was just a damned '.'
Thanks you saved me some hours.