# threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been trying to follow [this turorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid?hl=pl#ex) in order to implement openID authentication on an app, but I am completely lost. No matter what I tried, I kept getting this error:

```
Fatal error when loading application configuration:
Invalid object:
threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: main.py
```

Does anyone know how to implement openID logins?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447879/error-python-2-7-on-google-app-engine-threadsafe-cannot-be-enabled-with-cgi-ha

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This has nothing to do with OpenID.

If you use the new Concurrent Requests (**threadsafe=true**) mode with python 2.7 in Google App Engine you have to make sure that you specify a WSGI application (e.g. myapp.app) instead of a CGI handler (e.g. myapp.py) in app.yaml (see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/migrate27#wsgi) for more details):

Looks something like this:

app.yaml:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
   - url: /.*
    script: myapp.app
```

main.py:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.out.write('Hello, WebApp World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])

""" Old code:
def main():
  run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
"""
```

Alternatively you can also disable concurrent requests (**threadsafe=false**) and use your old CGI handler.

Comment: once you fixed the error the example in the tutorial you posted in your questions should work.

Comment: woohoo, i got it now :D Thank You

Comment: I had to disable it while using django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler() as app :(

Comment: is there a benefit to threadsafe: true vs making it false? I'm not a coder, so I'm hesitant to make code changes someone else's application... but the threadsafe setting is more approachable for me.